# What is the ':input[name=???]' of a subform field?

Tags: 8, forms

and thank you for your contribution.

I have created a custom content type with a field (`field_table_2`) that is a (list of) paragraph element reference entity.

The paragraph entity, contains 'select' fields (e.g. `field_rsn`, `field_added`, `field_deleted`,...), that we need to hide or show according to selection.

We are reading about [Conditional-form-fields](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/form-api/conditional-form-fields), but we cannot find a way to refer to the subform field, eg.:

```
$form['field_table_2']['widget'][0]['subform']['field_added']['$states'] = [
        'visible' => [
          ':input[name="???"]' => ['value' => 'Added'], // name of 'field_rsn'
        ]
];
```

What should be the name of `field_rsn` in the `':input'` ?

Are there any ideas/ examples? Are conditional-form-fields possible with 'paragraphs', 'entity references', or in general existing fields in the `hook_form_alter`?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "that we need to hide or show according to selection.". What selection?
"(list of) paragraph element" by this you mean unlimited field?
The input name is the name of input, isn't? All form fields have its 'name' attribute so the form can distinguish all form fields.
If you are working with nodes and paragraphs, what is the reason to use hook_form_alter?
Please explain futher.

Comment: @devicaru thank you. .. it was so simple.